# When does '.' not match in a Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I encountered the following problem (simplified). I wrote the following

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Fig.*");
String s = readMyString();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
```

In reading one string the matcher failed to match even though it started with "Fig". I tracked the problem down to a rogue character in the next part of the string. It had codePoint value 1633 from

```
(int) charAt(i)
```

but did not match the regex. I think it is due to a non-UTF-8 encoding somewhere in the input process.

The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) say:

> Predefined character classes
> .  Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

Presumably this is not a character in the strict sense of the word, but is is still part of the String. How do I detect this problem?

UPDATE: It was due to a (char)10 which was not easy to spot. My diagnosis above is wrong and all answers below are relevant to the question as asked and are useful.

Comment: Can you show an example of a `String` returned by `readMyString()`?

Comment: No, because I think it will get corrupted by cut-and-paste (the offending character does not print)

Comment: I tried with `"Fig\u0661"` and it matches correctly.

Comment: @Howard yes - if you construct the string yourself it works.

Comment: By 1633, do you mean 1633(decimal) or 0x661(hex): http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0661/index.htm ?

Comment: Any chance that there is a trailing newline which is not matched?

Comment: I will print out the char values. This may be slightly different from my example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.` character in a Java regex matches any character *except* line terminators, unless you use the flag `Pattern.DOTALL` when compiling your pattern.

To do so, you would use a Pattern like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("somepattern", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: You can also represent the option as a flag using `(?s)` in the beginning of your pattern string, as stated here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL. This may be more convenient if you're using a more compact syntax, or in my case, using Scala.

Answer (score 13):

It's easy enough to check this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".");
        for (char c = 0; c < 0xffff; c++) {
            String text = String.valueOf(c);
            if (!pattern.matcher(text).matches()) {
                System.out.println((int) c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my box, the output is:

```
10
13
133
8232
8233
```

Of these, 10 and 13 are "\n" and "\r" respectively. 133 (U+0085) is "next line", 8232 (U+2028) is "line separator" and 8233 (U+2029) is "paragraph separator".

Note that:

- This doesn't test any Unicode characters outside the basic multi-lingual plane
- It only uses the default options
- It seems to contradict your experience of character 1633 (U+0661)

Comment: Checking is one way, but the documentation should be clear enough on this point.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes, that's fair. It's informative to see which characters count as line breaks though :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `.` can have **3 slightly different interpretations** depending on the flags.

#### By default

`.` will exclude [line terminators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt) when [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode and [`UNIX_LINES`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNIX_LINES) mode are disabled (default):

> A line terminator is a one- or two-character sequence that marks the end of a line of the input character sequence. The following are recognized as line terminators:
>
> - A newline (line feed) character (`'\n'`),
> - A carriage-return character followed immediately by a newline character (`"\r\n"`),
> - A standalone carriage-return character (`'\r'`),
> - A next-line character (`'\u0085'`),
> - A line-separator character (`'\u2028'`), or
> - A paragraph-separator character (`'\u2029'`).

This means that `.` is equivalent to `[^\n\r\u0085\u2028\u2029]` in this case.

#### When `UNIX_LINES` mode is enabled, but `DOTALL` mode is disabled

`.` will exclude **only** `\n` when [`UNIX_LINES`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNIX_LINES) mode is enabled, but [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode is disabled. This means that `.` is equivalent to `[^\n]` in this case.

> If [`UNIX_LINES`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNIX_LINES) mode is activated, then the only line terminators recognized are newline characters.

#### When `DOTALL` mode is enabled

If [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode is enabled, `.` will match any character **without exception**.

> The regular expression `.` matches any character except a line terminator unless the [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag is specified.

Answer (score 1):

About working with regex non printing characters you can read this two articles:

1. [How to match nonprintable characters with a regular expression](http://web.archive.org/web/20130826142223/http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/214-how-to-match-nonprintable-characters-with-a-regular-expression)
2. [How to use Unicode code points, properties, blocks, and scripts in regular expressions](http://web.archive.org/web/20131104102548/http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/215-how-to-use-unicode-code-points-properties-blocks-and-scripts-in-regular-expressions/)

There is a lot of surprises even when you work exactly with UTF.