# Java - Split string

Tags: java, string, split

i have string which is separated by `"."` when i try to split it by the `dot` it is not getting spitted.

Here is the exact code i have. Please let me know what could cause this not to split the string.

```
public class TestStringSplit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testStr = "[Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;";
        String test[] = testStr.split(".");
        for (String string : test) {
            System.out.println("test : " + string);
        }
        System.out.println("Str Length : " + test.length);
    }
}
```

I have to separate the above string and get only the last part. in the above case it is `CreateRequisitionRO` not `CreateRequisitionRO;` please help me to get this.

Comment: i get the last value like `System.out.println("Last Value : " + test[test.length-1]);` it also prints the last one as `CreateRequisitionRO;`  but what i want is `CreateRequisitionRO` how to get this

Comment: see my answer. second part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The split() method in Java does not work on a dot (.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935858/the-split-method-in-java-does-not-work-on-a-dot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split this string through `StringTokenizer`  and get each word between dot

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(string, ".");
String firstToken = tokenizer.nextToken();
String secondToken = tokenizer.nextToken();
```

As you are finding for last word **CreateRequisitionRO** you can also use

```
String testStr = "[Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;";
String yourString = testStr.substring(testStr.lastIndexOf('.')+1, testStr.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String testStr = "[Lcom.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO;";
String test[] = testStr.split("\\.");
for (String string : test) {
    System.out.println("test : " + string);
}
System.out.println("Str Length : " + test.length);
```

The "." is a regular expression wildcard you need to escape it.

Answer (score 3):

Change `String test[] = testStr.split(".");` to `String test[] = testStr.split("\\.");`.

As the argument to [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regex argument, you need to escape the dot character (which means wildcard in regex):

Answer (score 3):

Note that [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes in a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), and `.` has special meaning in regular expression (which [matches **any character** except for line separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150214/when-does-not-match-in-a-regex/16150779#16150779)), so you need to escape it:

```
String test[] = testStr.split("\\.");
```

Note that you escape the `.` at the level of regular expression once: `\.`, and to specify `\.` in a string literal, `\` needs to be escaped again. So the string to pass to `String.split` is `"\\."`.

Or another way is to specify it inside a character class, where `.` loses it special meaning:

```
String test[] = testStr.split("[.]");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `.` as it is a special character, a [full list of these is available](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/syntax.html). Your split line needs to be:

```
String test[] = testStr.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Split takes a regular expression as a parameter. If you want to split by the literal ".", you need to escape the dot because that is a special character in a regular expression. Try putting 2 backslashes before your dot ("\\.") - hopefully that does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
String test[] = testStr.split("\\.");
```