# Why is this Java regex not working?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to match any string consisting of:

1. Any alphanumeric string of 1+ chars; then
2. Two periods (`".."`); then
3. Any alphanumeric string of 1+ chars

For example:

```
mydatabase..mytable
anotherDatabase23..table28
```

etc.

Given the following function:

```
public boolean isValidDBTableName(String candidate) {
    if(candidate.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+..[a-zA-Z0-9]+"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Passing this function the value `"mydb..tablename"` causes it to return `false`. Why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the candidate doesn't contain any other character? Like \n? The dots should be escaped, but it should match anyway. Also, you shouldn't create if-else for returning a boolean value. Just return the result of the expression.

Answer (score 11):

As NeplatnyUdaj has pointed out in comment, your current regex should return `true` for the input `"mydb..tablename"`.

However, your regex has the problem of over-matching, where it returns `true` for invalid names such as `nodotname`.

You need to escape `.`, since in Java regex, [it will match any character except for line separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150214/when-does-not-match-in-a-regex/16150779#16150779):

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
```

In regex, you can escape meta-characters (character with special meaning) with `\`. To specify `\` in string literal, you need to escape it again.

Comment: It is not the reason. The OP's example should be match as well since dot matches any character INCLUDING a dot. The problem will be elsewhere

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj: Didn't read the question carefully, but the fix is necessary to prevent `random.random` from being matched.

Comment: nhahtdh: Of course the OP's regexp is incorrect and your's is fine. I'm just pointing out that it should match the examples anyway(I've tried that).

Answer (score 3):

You must escape the period in regexes. As a `\` must also be escaped, this gives

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just  tried your regex in Eclipse and it worked. Or at least did not fail. Try stripping whitespace characters.

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    String testString = "mydb..tablename";
    Assert.assertTrue("no match", testString.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+..[a-zA-Z0-9]+"));
    Assert.assertFalse("falsematch", "a.b".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+..[a-zA-Z0-9]+"));


}
```